# sass won't install with yarn and fs module not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sass, fs

I'm beginner in ReactJS, NextJS and i have two inconsistent issues that I just can't figure out are happening in my project.

### Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

```
wait  - compiling...
error - ./node_modules/destroy/index.js:16:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js
./node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js
./node_modules/body-parser/index.js
./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
./node_modules/express/index.js
./root/server/test.js
./root/components/Modal/RegisterModal.jsx
./root/components/Modal/LoginModal.jsx
./root/components/Nav/Nav.jsx
./root/components/Home/Home.jsx
./pages/index.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

I don't understand why this error occurs when Express is used.

### Sass

While compiling my project, an error that has never appeared before occurs

```
error - ./root/styles/button.scss
To use Next.js' built-in Sass support, you first need to install `sass`.
Run `npm i sass` or `yarn add sass` inside your workspace.

Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/install-sass
```

I looked for days how to solve these two problems there, but even on StackOverflow, I can't solve the problem despite the number of solutions given.
Sorry for the lack of information but I really can't figure out why these problems are happening.

Comment: I installed fs today with npm. It is no longer a valid app. Open your version up in Node Modules and see if thats what it says in the readme